# Defining POJO id in Spring form for single object

Tags: java, forms, spring, jsp, tags

this is what controller sends to me:

```
model.addAttribute("weather", weatherService.getWeatherByCity(id));
```

this is my JSP:

```
<form:form commandName="newWeather" method="post" action="edit">
    <c:forEach items="${cities}" var="city">
        <form:input path="temperature"></form:input>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </c:forEach>
</form:form>
```

Problem:

I get one object from database named `weather`. I want to edit that by changing temperature. So I must send back atleast `id` and field `temperature`. I know how to send back temperature as shown, but how can I send back my `id`.

I think I can get it from model by `${weather.id}`, but how can I place it in form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="${weather.id}">
```